# Chaining sed statements

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm running a dozen of `sed` commands for each Capistranio deploy and I was wondering, if it's possible to chain them into 1 single `sed` command, instead of firing dozens at the server.

```
task :taskname do
    {:'foo' => foo, :'bar' => bar, :'foobar' => foobar, :'fubar' => fubar }.each do |search, replace|
        run "sed -i 's/#{search}/#{replace}/' file.ext"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` natively accepts a dozen of patterns (if you for some reason prefer `sed`):

```
{:foo => foo, :bar => bar, :foobar => foobar, :fubar => fubar}.inject("") do |acc, k, v|
  acc += " -e 's/#{k}/#{v}'"
end

run "sed #{acc} file.ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does mudasobwa's code work? With my Ruby (v1.9.3), it has to be:

```
acc = {:foo => foo, :bar => bar, :foobar => foobar, :fubar => fubar}.inject("") do |m, p|
  m + " -e 's/#{p[0]}/#{p[1]}'"
end

run "sed #{acc} file.ext"
```

Comment: I didn't use mudasobwa's _exact_ code, this is what I did: http://pastebin.com/sVTWqN6e